# Как подружить docker-compose образы

Tags: docker-compose

есть docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: "mysql"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "1234"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /c/Users/homework/docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  php:
    image: "php:7.4-fpm"
    restart: always
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
  nginx:
    image: "nginx"
    depends_on:
      - php
      - db
    links:
      - php
    volumes:
      - /c/Users/homework:/var/www
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

Операционная система WINDOWS 8.1 Профессиональная
вбиваю последовательно команды

```
D: && cd D:\Михаил\homework\docker && docker-compose up -d --build

docker-compose exec nginx /bin/bash
```

заходит внутрь образа nginx затем вбиваю команду `php -v` - пишет что такая команда не найдена

Я новичок в docker.

Вопрос: как мне настроить docker-compose.yml чтобы заходя в образ nginx можно было бы запускать  php файлы и уж после этого настраивать config nginx для работы с php-fpm?

Comment: А зачем вам php в nginx?

Comment: Контейнеры - не виртуальные машины. В них вообще заходить не нужно без крайней необходимости.

Comment: я хочу чтобы контейнер  nginx смог запускать php скрипты в браузере. Я же настраиваю nginx маршрутизацию и  указываю парсер php файлов